# Designing a generic datastructures/storage for Container->(Container)->Item

Tags: c#, sql, generics

I have a problem trying to design some generic storage..

Basically I have the following 4 objects

Pallet
Box
Parcel
Item

The top 3 are all containers, which can contain anything lower in the heirarchy than itself.
Initially, it was forced so that Pallets contain boxes, boxes contain parcels, parcels contain items.
But now I want it so some of the 'middle' containers can be skipped:
EG,  Pallets contain Parcels which contain Items (no cartons)
EG2, Pallets contain Items (no Cartons or items).

At the moment I have a database table for each of these objects.
But it's becoming messy to design a way to keep track of everything.

In Code, I'm presented with other problems, eg to print the contents of a pallet, initially would be:

```
class Pallet : List<Box> {}
class Box : List<Parcel> {}
class Parcel : List<Item> {}
class Item {}


class Pallet : List<Box>
{
    void Print()
    { 
        foreach (Box b in this)
            foreach (Parcel p in b)
                foreach (Item i in p)
                    //Print
    }
}
```

But now since I dont know what will be inside, I'm not sure how to go about it.

I'm hoping someone can give me advice on designing a good data structure or method of storing everything in a good and efficient manner.
I could do something like:

```
class Pallet : List<T>
{
    void Print()
    {
        if (this[0] is Box)
            //do this
        if (this[0] is Parcel)
            //do this, etc
    }
}
```

But it seems horribly messy.

I hope you can see what I am trying to do.

Comment: Can a Pallet contain 1 box, 1 parcel (which is not in a box) and 1 item (which is not in a parcel)?

Comment: No they will never be mixed. A pallet will either contain all box's or all items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can't you simply derive each container from the exact same base class? Then you could have something like the following:

```
public abstract class Container
{
    public abstract void Print();

    public List<Container> Contents { get; set; }
}

public class Box : Container
{
    public override void Print() 
    {
        foreach (Container c in Contents)
            Console.WriteLine("I am a {0}", c.ToString());
    }

}
```

This means that any container can contain a number of other containers. Of course you will need to implement some logic to control this, you don't want a Box containing too many Parcels, but a Box could contain another box provided it was smaller. Now you would say "but Item would have to also inherit from COntainer to be contained within a Box", and you would be right, but you can still use inheritance and a simple small change:

```
public interface IContainable { }

public abstract class Container
{
    public virtual void Print() 
    {
        foreach (IContainable c in Contents)
            Console.WriteLine("I am a {0}", c.ToString());
    }

    public List<IContainable> Contents { get; set; }
}

public class Pallet : Container {  }

public class Box : Container, IContainable {  }

public class Item : IContainable { }
```

Using this approach means a `Pallet` can contain things, but it cannot be contained. An `Item` can be contained but isn't a container.

You can also store all your containers in the same self-referencing database table - they don't need to be separated out. Each contained item can simply have a foriegn key back to another entry in the same table that is its container.

Answer (score 1):

> But now I want it so some of the 'middle' containers can be skipped

I would reconsider that. It looks simple but essentially you are creating a second, parallel, data structure here. It introduces a whole new set of constraints.

The best 'workaround' might be to give each Pallet a default (nameless) Box etc.

Answer (score 1):

You've taken a step too far and actually made your design worse, in my opinion.  I would advise returning to your original constraint of Pallets containing Boxes, etc, but with a minor modification.

If you add a parcel to a pallet, create a 'dummy' box to put it in, with a property that indicates it is a 'dummy' entity.

You can then keep your existing, tidy, structure.  But also have added flexibility.